# Disable caret for non-input elements?

Tags: html, css, caret

Is it possible to disable the blinking caret on an HTML document for elements that are non-input elements?

For example, clicking a list item will move the caret to the list item element:

```
<ul>
  <li>Cool choice 1</li>
  <li>Cool choice 2</li>
  <li>Cool choice 3</li>
</ul>
```

If you have an `ul` that you're using for navigation then you may want them to feel like buttons. This could be achieved if the caret weren't in play. Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this class

```
.disableCaret{
  -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
   user-select: none;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this at the top of your css. This targets every element that's not an input and sets the cursor to the default arrow.

**CSS**

```
*:not(input) {
    cursor: default;
}
```

Then for anything you want to appear clickable you can just add a class like this.

**CSS**

```
.clickable {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Ah, never mind that! I thought you meant the carrot looking cursor when hovering, not the constantly blinking one. That is a browser option.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Firefox with the option

```
accessibility.browsewithcaret
```

set to true. This option can be found in about:config or the first option in the advanced settings named `Always use the cursor keys to navigate within pages`.
If I guessed correct, this question has nothing to do with html nor css.

Answer (score 0):

To hide & disable the carrot icon for select or dropdown.

CSS

```
.form-select.disableCaret {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background-image: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form-select.disableCaret::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
 <select class="form-select disableCaret" id="diabeticYesNo" name="diabeticYesNo"
 aria-label="Floating label select example" required disabled>
    <option value="" {% if myForm.diabeticYesNo == 'NA' %}selected{% endif %} hidden>Select</option>
    <option value="Diabetic" {% if myForm.diabeticYesNo == 'Diabetic' %}selected{% endif %}>DM</option>
    <option value="Prediabetic" {% if myForm.diabeticYesNo == 'Prediabetic' %}selected{% endif %}>PD</option>
    <option value="NonDiabetic" {% if myForm.diabeticYesNo == 'NonDiabetic' %}selected{% endif %}>ND</option>
</select>
```