# How can I correct this in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way in CSS that I can disable this cursor on the page? So when the user click on page nothing appears.

I tried using cursor none but I don't want to change the mouse cursor, I want to change the click result.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add *all* the relevant code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+disable+cursor+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Please post CODE. Not pictures of code or in your case even worse, just a picture

Comment: Are you asking about the "carat"? This may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41167367/disable-caret-for-non-input-elements

Comment: @CBroe Some users use caret browsing (I believe toggle by f7 in Chrome) which will show the caret in any text. I don't know if that's the case here, but it sounds like it might be.

Comment: If this cursor only appears after the user clicked on this element - then it likely isn't "static" text, but some sort of input component - `input`, `textarea`, or any element with `contenteditable` set. Which one it actually is, we can hardly tell from your screenshot.

Comment: @DBS but that is for the normal "hovering" cursor, when that is moved over text, right? If this only shows after the user _clicks_ on the element here, then I am guessing it is something more than just that.

Comment: @CBroe I apologise if I'm missing the point, but caret browsing appears to add the caret to any text I click while it's enabled, e.g. I can click part way through your comment and leave a caret there while my mouse moves away.

Comment: @DBS if it is indeed that (https://www.makeuseof.com/what-is-caret-browsing/), you might be right. Can't test it right now, because on Mac this feature appears to have been disabled/removed. We need clarity from the OP here, I suppose.